# Fontsize for devices with same dp Widht and dp Height but different densities

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen, textview

I've working on a aplication that show some text in several fragments, and got some problem with text sizes in diferent screens, I use three phones for testing

**MOTO E        density->1.5, dpheight->592.0, dpwidht->360.0

MOTO G      density->2.0, dpheight->592.0, dpwidht->360.0

S3 MINI     density->1.5, dpheight->533.3333, dpwidht->320.0**

for target the S3 MINI I use the folder **'values-w320dp'**

the logic may say that for targetting to

MOTO G should use **'values-w360dp-xhdpi'**

and for MOTO E should use **'values-w360dp-hdpi'**

but its not displaying well on neighter of them, it looks like its getting values from standard **'values'** folder

Which is the right approach in order to point for the MOTO E and MOTO G values folders?

Thanks

Comment: Are you putting the text sizes into a dimens file inside of those folders?

Comment: yes I do, each folder has a dimens.xml with different values in sp

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the right approach in order to point for the MOTO E and MOTO G values folders?

use,

`values-sw720dp-xhdpi` for moto g  and `values-sw480dp-hdpi` for moto e

Comment: I've tested the answer and it's not working, the app running on moto e and moto g takes its values from default files (dimens.xml and strings.xml)<br/>Why use "720" besides "360"?, 720 is the pixel size, but the Docs says that should use dp